# How do I fix the Domain Translation issue in Windows 11 Pro Domain member?

Tags: windows, administrator, windows-domain, join

[image]

I followed the directions to Join my Windows 11 Pro PC to the AD Domain and setup the Domain IP as the DNS Server for the Win11 PC.  The Join went as required without errors. The Domain account that I wanted to use on the PC is a member of the Domain Admins so it was automatically added to the PC's Administrator group.  Rebooted the PC and when I checked the Administrator Group, I noticed that the Domain Admins Group is not fully translated, as indicated in the screen capture below.  How do I correct this issue, please?

Comment: Have you tried a “gpupdate /force” and “GPUpdate /logoff”

Comment: Hi...  thank you for the suggestion.  I ran both and rebooted.  No change.  Translation is not working.